# github branching and merging

Tags: github, merge, branch

I'm relatively new to github (I've pushed my rails app to a repo and I push it up regularly to keep it updated, with a 'commit' message, which is very handy to see where I am) and I just want to check I'm about to do the next stage correctly, without messing it all up.

Some history: a few months ago a software development company sent me the source code of the project, which I tasked them to do. It's called Project_v_1. Over the months I've been making css/javascript/html changes - models and controllers not for me yet!

But I have done a substantial amount of work and, as I said, I update it regularly. Project_v_1 is the master branch (the only branch in the repo, in fact)

Now I'm about to receive Project_v_2 from the software company. I want to put the best of my changes I made to Project_v_1 into Project_v_2. Do I have to manually seek out the changes in the files I made and copy/paste them into P_v_2?

Or can I do something like:

- create a new branch in my repo: P_v_2
- put P_v_2 into that branch.
- merge P_v_2 and my master (P_v_1).

Am I scr**ed? It just seems a bit miraculous to think there's a simple resolution to my problem.

Thanks,
C

Comment: There's no simple resolution. The mistake was to have you and the software company working each in their corner, without synchronizing with each other. You should have shared a repo, and worked on the same repo, allowing changes to be merged on a regular basis. You can try rebasing your changes on the new version, but you're likely to have a large amount of conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

`git merge` will merge every commit in `v1` to `v2`. I suggest you to use `cherry-pick` which is useful to apply same commits between branches :

1. Checkout the `v2` branch and `git cherry-pick <your-best-commit-id>`